# Reading a C struct from POSIX shared memory in Python 3

Tags: python, c++, linux, shared-memory

There exists a block of shared memory containing a C `struct` which itself contains an array of `struct`s. What I'm after is deeper in that array. The layout in source looks roughly like the following:

(tl;dr - how would you do this?)

```c
struct proc_data
{
  pid_t proc_id;
  bool initialized;
  bool suppress;
  bool only;
  bool halt;

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_a;
  int64_t total_a;
  bool total_a_flag;

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_b;
  int64_t total_b;
  int64_t long_b;
  bool total_b_flag;

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_c;
  int64_t total_c;
  bool total_c_flag;

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_d;
  int64_t total_d;
  bool total_d_flag;

  std::atomic<int> garbage;
  std::atomic<bool> garbage2;
};

struct gloabl_data
{
  bool initialized;
  bool global_suppress;
  bool global_only;
  bool global_halt;

  uint p_proc_data[50];   //offsets for the following array
  struct proc_data proc_data_arr[50];
};
```

Pardon the anonymized naming conventions, but you know how it goes.

I'm successfully able to read into this shared memory block using `sysv_ipc` and can even get so far as to read each program's PID as the first member of each array element. Neat. The code below is functional for me:

```py
segment = SharedMemory(ftok(shm_keyfile, ord("r"), silence_warning = True))

offsets = list()

for i in range(0,50): #the hardcoded limit
    offsets.append(int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=4, offset=4+4*i), byteorder='little'))

for offset in offsets:
    pid = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=4, offset=offset), byteorder='little')
    if(pid == 0): continue

    proc = Process(pid)
    print(str(pid)+" "+str(proc.cmdline()))
```

However, once I get to the `pthread_mutex_t`s, it seems to all come apart. `sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)` is 40 bytes on my platform (x86_64), but of course there is probably some padding going on.

The code below continues on within the `for offset in offsets` loop:

```py
intra_offset = offset + 4

initialized = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1
suppress = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1
only = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1
halt = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little'))+"\n")
intra_offset += 1

intra_offset += sizeof_pthread_mutex_t # mutex_a
total_a = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=8, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 8
total_a_flag = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1

intra_offset += sizeof_pthread_mutex_t # mutex_b
total_b = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=8, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 8
long_b = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=8, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 8
total_b_flag = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1

intra_offset += sizeof_pthread_mutex_t # mutex_c
total_c = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=8, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 8
c_flag = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1

intra_offset += sizeof_pthread_mutex_t # open pnl mutex
total_d = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=8, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 8
total_d_flag = int.from_bytes(segment.read(byte_count=1, offset=intra_offset), byteorder='little')))
intra_offset += 1
```

And, of course, the values I get from that are just junk after the first mutex. I adjust my presumed size of the mutexes and add some padding here and there, but can't quite seem to get a good, sensible output.

My actual question here is - is there a simpler way to do this? I haven't seen a suitable way to do this via Python's `ctypes`, though I'd love to go that route.

Any and all feedback is welcome. =)